# Remove small kink in tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex

I have made this graphic using tikz:
[image]
Sourcecode:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}  
\usepackage{tikz}   
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, calc, positioning, fit, external}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1.4, domain=-5:5, samples=49, text height=1.5ex, text depth=.25ex]]
\centering
\def\w0{0.7}
\def\z0{1.25}
\def\hype{\w0*sqrt(1 + (\x / \z0)^2)}

\fill[fill=red!10] (-5,0) -- plot(\x,{\hype}) -- plot[domain=5:-5](\x,{- \hype}) -- cycle;
\draw[color=red,very thick] plot (\x,{\hype});
\draw[color=red,very thick] plot (\x,{- \hype});

\draw[color=gray,dashed] plot (\x,{\x * \w0 / \z0});
\draw[color=gray,dashed] plot (\x,{-\x * \w0 / \z0});
\draw[color=black,thick,loosely dashdotted] (-5,0) -- (5,0);

\draw[dashed] (0, 0) -- (0, -2.5);
\draw[dashed] (\z0, 0) -- (\z0, -2.5);
\draw[<->, thick] (0, -2.3) -- (\z0, -2.3) node[midway,above]{$z_r$};

\draw[<->, thick] (0, -\w0) -- (0, \w0) node[midway,fill=white]{$w_0$};
\draw[<->, thick] (\z0, {-sqrt(2)*\w0}) -- (\z0, {sqrt(2)*\w0}) node[midway,fill=white]{$\sqrt{2}\,w_0$};

\node[draw,color=green,thick,circle,minimum size=1.5cm] at (-4.9, 2.8) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The green circle is just there to mark the problem. How do I remove the kink? It is gone when I specify a low number of samples, but then the hyperbola looks crappy. The more samples, the more pronounced the kink is.

Comment: Not sure how to explain that, but since the incriminating plot is simply a line, you could reduce the number of `samples` to `2` for that plot: `\draw[color=gray,dashed] plot[samples=2] (\x,{-\x * \w0 / \z0});` That solves the problem.

Comment: Looks like a rounding error. It can also be fixed with `\draw[color=gray,dashed] plot (\x,{\x * (\w0 / \z0)});` (note the brackets).

Comment: Here's a related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77624/pgf-math-engine-imprecise

Comment: The added brackets `(w0/z0)` work for me.  Alternative specify the domain as `-5.01:5.01` for these lines.

Comment: (w0/z0) did work for me. Specifying only two samples got me the wrong lines. (They should be asymptotes, not parallel to asymptotes.)

Comment: With pgf 3, it works as intended.

Comment: @HarishKumar Can you write an answer for this?

Comment: @percusse I am not sure why the error comes in v2.1. Could not check as I have have that version anymore. I will be glad to upvote if you add an answer :)

Comment: @HarishKumar It's now the official release if DasKrumelmonster agrees we can close this as *package update fixes it* I guess

Comment: @percusse Is it official now? Wow. Yes I agree. in that case the question becomes redundant and we can ask the OP to update. :)

Comment: Some users use pgf 2.1 and if  pgf 3 is the norm now, we need to review (revisit ?) some answers : for example about activ characters, now there is the tikz library babel to avoid problem with some activ characters. There is also the angles library and a lot of questions may have better answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid the problem with pgf 2.1 and with the next code

```
 \draw[color=gray,dashed] plot (\x,{\x * (\w0 / \z0)});
 \draw[color=gray,dashed] plot (\x,{-\x * (\w0 / \z0)});
```

Remark :

a) Two points are enough to draw a line  with pgf 2 or pgf 3. so :

```
   \draw[color=gray,dashed,samples=2] plot (\x,{\x * (\w0 / \z0)});
   \draw[color=gray,dashed,samples=2] plot (\x,{-\x * (\w0 / \z0)});
```

b) No problem with pgf 3.0

Comment: Just as a clarification: The problem is solved by the added parenthesis, not by the reduced sampling. See my answer for a picture.

Comment: Yes you are right with parenthesis under pgf 2.1 the problem is solved. I think it's very natural to use parenthesis in this case. If only ´samples=2´ With pgf 2, I'm not sure to get the fine line because the points are perhaps wrong

Answer (score 0):

Note that samples=2 **seems** to eliminate the problem (as there is a smooth line) but the line is in the wrong place:

[image]

Code:

```
\draw[color=gray,dashed] plot (\x,{-\x * \w0 / \z0});
\draw[color=gray, samples=2] plot (\x,{-\x * \w0 / \z0});
```

So this is no solution.

---

Besides the awkward "change the parenthesis" thing, there is another solution: Replace

```
\usepackage{tikz}
```

with

```
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
```

or even just

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
```

and it works. (Don't forget to declare `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}`) After gaining some experience in pgfplots and tikz, I recommend using pgfplots with a proper axis environment for anything related to graphs of functions.

But upgrading to PGF 3 is probably the best solution.

At the moment I can't find an easy way to upgrade. (Using MikTeX 2.9)

Comment: PGF 3.0 is now on CTAN, and at least in TeX Live. Probably soon in MikTeX as well, if not there already. Hence, updating your distro as usual will work.